# Load Keras model with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, keras, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy a NN model that I trained locally on my machine using Keras. I use my model (locally) as:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model("/path/to/model/model.h5")
prediction = model.predict(x)
```

Now, I need to use the same model on my lambda function. I uploaded the model in an `s3` bucket. I then tried to access the file as:

```
model = load_model("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/models/model.h5")
```

But it tells me that the file does not exist. I guess it's a privilege problem. I also tried as (similar to how I read JSON files from `s3`):

```
client_s3 = boto3.client("s3")
result = client_s3.get_object(Bucket="my-bucket", Key='models/model.h5')
model = load_model(result["Body"].read())
```

But I obtain this error:

```
"stackTrace": [
[
  "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
  322,
  "lambda_handler",
  "model = load_model(result[\"Body\"].read())"
],
[
  "/var/task/keras/models.py",
  227,
  "load_model",
  "with h5py.File(filepath, mode='r') as f:"
],
[
  "/var/task/h5py/_hl/files.py",
  269,
  "__init__",
  "fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)"
],
[
  "/var/task/h5py/_hl/files.py",
  99,
  "make_fid",
  "fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)"
],
[
  "h5py/_objects.pyx",
  54,
  "h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper",
  null
],
[
  "h5py/_objects.pyx",
  55,
  "h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper",
  null
],
[
  "h5py/h5f.pyx",
  78,
  "h5py.h5f.open",
  null
],
[
  "h5py/defs.pyx",
  621,
  "h5py.defs.H5Fopen",
  null
],
[
  "h5py/_errors.pyx",
  123,
  "h5py._errors.set_exception",
  null
]
],
"errorType": "UnicodeDecodeError",
"errorMessage": "'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 29: invalid start byte"
}
```

I suspect the `result["Body"].read()` function cannot be used with `h5py` object. What is the best way to load a `h5py` model from `s3`?

**SOLUTION**: The solution is to download the file into the `/tmp/` folder:

```
result = client_s3.download_file("my-bucket",'model.h5', "/tmp/model.h5")
model = load_model("/tmp/day/model.h5")
```

Comment: Is the model.h5 file in the bucket is publicly accessible? If not use the AWS SDK for S3 to download the file and save it into /tmp folder and load to the model.

Comment: It's not public, I solved by downloading it. I updated the question with the solution

Answer (score 4):

### The problem

`boto3.client("s3")..get_object(...)["Body"].read()` returns a bytestring, but `keras.models.load_model` expects a filepath ([source](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model)).

### The solution

Store the file somewhere. [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) might come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Following links posted by @Raji, I discovered keras has [recently implemented](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/11636/files) functionality to load model files and/or weights files from google cloud storage.

First set up a new project on google cloud, and create a new bucket on google cloud storage, and upload your model file there. Or in my case, upload the weights file there (example address "gs://my-bucket/my_weights.hdf5"). Generate new service account credentials and download the corresponding json file into your repo and note the absolute filepath (like "/path/to/repo/my_credentials.json").

Set environment variables:

```sh
# .env
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/repo/my_credentials.json" 
MODEL_WEIGHTS_FILEPATH="gs://my-bucket/my_weights.hdf5"
```

FYI: I got errors like "All attempts to get a Google authentication bearer token failed" until I set the "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" env var to satisfy the implicit checks for credentials.

Load weights from google cloud storage:

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

MODEL_WEIGHTS_FILEPATH = os.getenv("MODEL_WEIGHTS_FILEPATH")

print(MODEL_WEIGHTS_FILEPATH)

# an optional check
import tensorflow as tf
tf.io.gfile.exists(MODEL_WEIGHTS_FILEPATH)

model = unweighted_model() # your keras model
weighted_model = model.load_weights(MODEL_WEIGHTS_FILEPATH)
weighted_model.predict("zyx") # predict or do whatever with your model
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9343#issuecomment-440903847

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, model_file_name) #.h5 file
body = obj.get()['Body'].read()

file_access_property_list = h5py.h5p.create(h5py.h5p.FILE_ACCESS)
file_access_property_list.set_fapl_core(backing_store=False)
file_access_property_list.set_file_image(body)  

file_id_args = {
    'fapl': file_access_property_list,
    'flags': h5py.h5f.ACC_RDONLY,
    'name': b'this should never matter',
}

h5_file_args = {
    'backing_store': False,
    'driver': 'core',
    'mode': 'r',
}

with contextlib.closing(h5py.h5f.open(**file_id_args)) as file_id:
    with h5py.File(file_id, **h5_file_args) as h5_file:
        loaded_model = load_model(h5_file)    #from keras.models
```

Now, `loaded_model` can be used to make predictions

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.download_file('bucket_name','file_name','model') #downloading the model to temporary file named "model"
with h5py.File('model','r') as f:
    model = load_model(f)
```